# Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 autoinstall not loading user-data anymore (packer)

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

So I have a weird problem: I am using packer to autoinstall Ubuntu Server 20.04 in VirtualBox. I am following this example:
https://nickcharlton.net/posts/automating-ubuntu-2004-installs-with-packer.html

Yesterday when I tried it for the first time it worked like a charm, packer even was able to connect via SSH to the vm that was created after install. Then I tried it again (with slight changes) and it just stoped working. I am unable to get it working again ever since.
The user-data is not loaded anymore and the installer runs with GUI, asking questions as if no autoinstall was run. I have confirmed (by aborting install and then Alt+F2 -> curl -ls http://10.0.2.2:PACKERPORT) that packers http-directory can be reached by the vm and there are user-data and meta-data files there.

How can it be that it worked once and then it stopped working? What the hell?
I am using the same boot-command as in the example. I have confirmed that the bootcommand is correctly set during vm-boot-up. My user-data contains this:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: test_vm
    password: $6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0
    username: testmann
  locale: de_DE.UTF-8
  keyboard:
    layout: de
  early-commands:
    # otherwise packer tries to connect and exceed max attempts:
    - systemctl stop ssh
  ssh:
    install-server: true
```

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to fix it by providing this additonal statement to the boot-command:

`cloud-config-url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/user-data`

My entire Boot-Command now is:

```
boot_command = [
    "<enter><wait><enter><f6><esc><wait> ",
    "autoinstall<wait>",
    " cloud-config-url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/user-data<wait>",
    " ds='nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/'",
    "<wait5><enter>"
  ]
```

Comment: As a Note: In my experience with packer and ubuntu autoinstall it is less troublesome to use packers cd-rom-host functionality than the http-server. All I had to change was to replace the http-related properties in the install script (http_directory, http_port_max, http_port_min) with the cd-related config. I left the user-data and meta-data files in the http-dir and put this into the install script:

cd_files    = ["./http/*"]
cd_label    = "cidata"

Then I removed everything http-related after "autoinstall" from the boot-comand and that's it.